# Issues with Bootstrap Grid Alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

[image: layout]

I need this layout (see picture), I tried a lot but nothing works.. here is my code:

```
<div class="row content-container">

            <div class="col-md-9" id="map-content">
            <h1>#Map</h1>

        </div> <!-- MAP -->

        <div class="col-md-3" id="route">
        <h1>#Route</h1>
        </div> <!-- Route -->

        <div class="col-md-9" id="breadcrumbs">
        </div> <!-- Breadcrumbs -->


    </div> <!--Row Content-->
```

Comment: It is completely unclear as to what you are asking. Your image does not identify anything related to your code as far as which column goes where and if these columns are meant to stack in a particular order on mobile etc. You need to supply more information/context. See [ask] > and also > [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qVyLf/301/).

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row ">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="background: green; height: 60px;">Aaa</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="background: red; height: 60px;">Bbb</div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background: blue; height: 120px;">Bbb</div>

  </div>  

</div>
```